# Are we asking too many 'what' and not enough 'why' or 'how' questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

This might just be a gut feeling because of the frequency and timing of when I view the questions on UXSE, but for some reason I keep seeing questions about 'what is the best way to ' which I guess is fine because there will always be people wanting to get their problems solved in the same way as what StackOverflow provides for programmers and developers, but I am sure deep down inside there are lots of people who want to explore 'why' we do certain things (i.e. are the so called 'guidelines' and 'standards' really being followed or blindly followed) or 'how' we do certain things (e.g. how to design ethically and efficiently).

What are people's feelings about the proportion of 'what' versus 'how' and 'why' questions? And does this reflect the maturity of the profession as well as the make up of the UXSE community?